# What does data serialization do?

Tags: c++, serialization

I'm having a hard time understanding what serialization is and does.

Let me simplify my problem. I have a `struct info` in my c/c++ programs, and I may store this `struct` data into a file `save.bin` or send it via socket to another computer.

```
struct info {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

void write_to_file()
{
    info a = {"Steve", 10};
    ofstream ofs("save.bin", ofstream::binary);
    ofs.write((char *) &a, sizeof(a));   // am I doing it right?
    ofs.close();
}

void write_to_sock()
{
    // I don't know about socket api, but I assume write **a** to socket is similar to file, isn't it?
}
```

`write_to_file` will simply save the `struct info` object `a` to disk, making this data persistent, right? And write it to socket is pretty much the same, right?

In the above code, I don't think I used **data serialization**, but the data `a` is made persistent in `save.bin` anyway, right?

**Question**

1. Then what's the point of serialization? Do I need it here? If yes, how should I use it?
2. I always think that any kind of files, `.txt/.csv/.exe/...`, are bits of `01` in memory, which means they have binary representation naturally, so can't we simply send these files via socket directly?

Code example is highly appreciated.

Comment: No use, if both client and server is maintained by you.!!!!

Comment: @Anonymous, if both are not maintained by me?

Comment: You have to abide by standard and thats where serialization comes into play.

Comment: @Anonymous, could you plz examplify it with some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the data a is made persistent in save.bin anyway, right?

No! Your struct contains an `std::string`. The exact implementation (and the binary data you get with a cast to `char*` is not defined by the standard, but the actual string data will always resign somewhere outside of the class frame, heap-allocated, so you can't save that data this easily. With properly done serialisation, the string data is written to where the rest of the class also end up, so you will be able to read it back from a file. That's what you need serialisation for.

How to do it: you have to encode the string in some way, the easiest way is to first write its length, then the string itself. On reading back the file, first read back the length, then read that amount of bytes into a new string object.

> I always think that any kind of files, .txt/.csv/.exe/..., are bits of 01 in memory

Yes, but the problem is that it's not universally defined which bit represents what part of a data structure. In particular, there are [little-endian and big-endian architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), they store the bits "the other way around". If you naïvely read out a file written in a mismatching architecture, you will obviously get garbage.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. By "encode the string in some way", do you mean I'd better encode the string using utf-8 or something like this? But do I really need to do this? I mean just like you said, I can simply write the length of the string into the binary file to indicate how long the string is, or maybe I can just append a `'\0'` at the end of the string when I write it into the binary file, right?

Comment: The string encoding (UTF-8 etc.) is another issue; you don't really need to worry about that when saving to a file, only when e.g. displaying or trimming the string. Here I meant by "encoding", serialising the string object. — Yes, you can also append a `'\0'`, instead of first writing the length, but that's IME rather more cumbersome (though very common, after all that's the standard way C handles strings with not-compile-time-known length). Length-encoding is of course a bit more wasteful on memory, but if the strings are sufficiently long not significantly so.

Answer (score 5):

Just writing down binary in-memory images is a form of serialization and for trivial cases it works. However in general you need to solve a few more problems that just dumping the memory doesn't consider:

### 1. Pointers

If the data contains any pointer of course you cannot just dump an load later as the memory address of where the pointers are pointing to will have no meaning once the program terminates and is restarted. Many objects have "hidden" pointers... for example there's no way to dump an `std::vector` in memory and reload it later correctly... `sizeof` on an `std::vector` clearly doesn't include the size of contained elements and therefore any structure containing an `std::vector` cannot be just dumped and reloaded. The same goes for `std::string` and all other `std` containers.

### 2. Portability

C and C++ struct and classes are not defined in terms of the bytes they occupy in memory, not portably that is. This means that a different compiler, a different compiler version or even the same version but with different compile options may generate code in which the structure layout in memory is not the same.

If you need serialization to just save and reload the data in the same program and that data it's not supposed to live long then memory dumping can indeed be used. Just think however about having millions of documents saved by just dumping structures and now the new compiler version (that you're **forced** to use because it's the only supported on the new OS version) has a different layout and you cannot load those documents any more.

In addition to same-system portability problems note also that even just a single integer can have a different in-memory representation on different systems. It may be larger or smaller; it may have a different byte ordering. Just using a memory dump means that what is saved cannot be loaded by another system. Not even a single integer.

### 3. Versioning

If the data you save will have a long lifespan then it's quite probable that you'll change the structures as the program evolves, for example you will add new fields, you will remove unused fields, you will change the general structure (e.g. changing a vector to a linked list).

If your format is just the memory images of current data structures it will be pretty hard to be able to later add for example a `color` field to a `polygon` object and having that the program can load old documents assuming as default color value the color that was used in the previous version.

Even writing a conversion program will be difficult because you will have old code able to load old documents and new code able to save new documents, but you cannot just "merge" the two and get a program that load old and saves new (i.e. both programs source code will have a `polygon` structure but with different fields, now what?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which makes me understand why serialization is paramount, :-). But how to use serialization here?

Comment: I wonder, as you said, `structure layout may vary with different compiler/platform`, so how could serialization handle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your string won't be saved correctly. If you have different machines their representations of integers might differ, different programming languages won't have the same representations for strings for instance.

But when you have pointers to members, you wil save the pointer address and not the pointed to member, which means you have no way of getting that data from file again. What if your structure needs to change? All software that uses your data will need to change.

Yes you can send files via socket, but you will need some kind of protocol in order to make sure you know the name of the file and when you've reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You're playing a game. On very hard mode. You reach the last level. You're happy. The 2 days of non-stop play are paying off. The plot will soon come to an end. You'll find the evil mastermind's motivation, how you got to be the hero and will collect the sought-after epic artifact that awaits behind that last door. **And** you got here without having to restart once.

Behind the scenes, there's a game object, that looks like this:

```
class GameState
{
   int level;
}
```

And the level is `25`.

You really enjoyed the game so far, but you don't want to start all over in case the last boss kills you. So, intuitively, you press `Ctrl+S`. But wait, you get an error:

```
Sorry, saving is disabled.
```

What? So I have to start all over in case I die? How can this be.

*Drumroll*

The developers, albeit brilliant (they managed to keep you hooked for 2 straight days, right?) didn't implement **serialization**.

When you restart the game, memory clean-up takes place. That all-important `GameState` object, the one you spent 2 days to increase the `level` member to `25`, is destroyed.

How could you fix this? The memory is reclaimed by the OS when you close the game. Where could you store it? On an external server? (sockets) On disk? (write to file)

Okay, why not.

```
class GameState
{
    int level;
    void save(const std::string& fileName)
    { /* write level to file */ }
    void load(const std::string& fileName)
    { /* read game state from file */ }
};
```

When you press `Ctrl+s`, the `GameState` object is saved to a file.

And, miraculously, when you load the game, the `GameState` object is read from that file. You no longer have to spend 2 days to get back to that last boss. You're already there.

**Real answer:**

Technically, writing serialization functionality is pretty difficult. I suggest you use a third-party. Google protocol buffers offers serialization that is cross-platform and even cross-language. Many others exist.

> 1.Then what's the point of serialization? Do I need it here? If yes, how should I use it?

As explained above, it stores state between runs, or between processes (possibly on different machines). Whether you needed or not depends on whether you need to store state and re-load it later.

> 2.I always think that any kind of files, .txt/.csv/.exe/..., are bits of 01 in memory, which means they have binary representation naturally, so can't we simply send these files via socket directly?

They are. But you don't want to modify the `.exe` whenever you play a new game.

Comment: Then what does this `protocol buffer` do and how does it do? Could you plz give me a simple rundown?

Comment: I wonder how protocol buffer handles those problems, such as different platforms have different representation for `int/string`, etc.

Comment: @Alcott it's open-source, feel free to see :)

Answer (score 3):

Serialization does a lot of things.  It supports persistence (being able
to leave the program, then come back to it and obtain the same data),
and communicating between processes and machines.  It basically means
converting your internal data to a sequence of bytes, and to be useful,
you have to support deserialization as well: converting the sequence of
bytes back into data.

When you do this, it's important to realize that internally to the
program, data isn't just a sequence of bytes.  It has format and 
structure: how a `double` is represented is different from one machine
to the next, for example; and more complex objects, like `std::string`,
aren't even in contiguous memory.  So the first thing you have to do
when you serialize is define how each type is represented as a sequence
of bytes.  If you're communicating with another program, both programs
have to agree on this serial format; if it's just so that you can reread
the data yourself, you can use any format you want (but I'd recommend
using a pre-defined standard format, like XDR, if only to simplify the
documentation).

What you cannot do is just dump out an image of the object in memory.
Complex objects like `std::string` will have pointers in them, and these
pointers will be meaningless in another process.  And even the
representation of simple types like `double` may change over time.  (The
migration from 32 bits to 64 resulted in the size of a `long` changing
on most systems.)  You must define a format, and then generate it byte
by byte, from the data you have.  To write XDR, for example, you might
use something like this:

```
typedef std::vector<char> Buffer;

void
writeUInt( Buffer& dest, unsigned value )
{
    dest.push_back( (value >> 24) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value >> 16) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value >>  8) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value      ) & 0xFF );
}

void
writeInt( Buffer& dest, int value )
{
    writeUInt( dest, static_cast<unsigned>( value ) );
}

void
writeString( Buffer& dest, std::string const& value)
{
    assert( value.size() <= 0xFFFFFFFF );
    writeInt( dest, value.size() )
    std::copy( value.begin(), value.end(), std::back_inserter( dest ) );
    while ( dest.size() % 4 != 0 ) {
        dest.push_back( '\0' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from big edian or little endian there's the issue of how the data is packed for the given stucture for that program with that compiler.  If you to save an entire structure, you can't use any pointers, you would have to replace it with a character buffer large enough for your needs.  If the other machine is going to be the same architecture, then if you use #pragma pack(1) there won't be any gaps between the fields of your structure and you can ensure that the data will appear as if it were serialized, but without the size prefix for your string.  You can skip the #pragma pack(1) if your certain that the other program that will read the data has the exact same settings for the same exact structure.  Outside of that, the data won't match up.

If you serialize to memory first, you can speed up the serialization process.  This can usually be accomplished with a buffer class and one templated function for most types.

```
template<typename T>
buffer& operator<<(T data)
{
    *(T*)buf = data;
    buf += sizeof(T);
}
```

Obviously you'll need specialized ones for strings and larger data types.  You can use memcpy for large structures and passed in pointers to data.  For strings, you'll want to prefix the length as was mentioned earlier.

For serious serialization needs, though, there's a lot more to consider.